# How do I post a job on StackOverflow?

Tags: acumatica

How do I post a job on your site for an Acumatica Specialist? I am needing to hire an Acumatica specialist with at least 3 years experience plus able to lead ERP technology?

Answer (score 1):

Job boards were removed.

source: https://goodbyestackoverflowjobs.com/